# D6 to D7 - Content Migration

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-7, migration

I have an existing site in drupal 6 and i need to rebuild the same in drupal 7. I experiencing some problems with content migration from D6 to D7. I tried with node export module with Drupal var export format and CSV format but both did not work. 
Is there any other approach to migrate all the contents from D6 to D7?  Any reference or tutorial to use migrate module for content migration.

Any solution for this issue will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drupal 7 version of the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) to migrate data from a D6 installation to a D7 installation.

For assistance, take a look at [Migrating D6 Content Construction Kit (CCK) to D7 Fields](http://drupal.org/node/1144136)